# Convert JsonObject to ParseObject in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, jsonparser, back4app

I am sending out ParseObject through push notification so that I may store them locally on the users device.
How can make a ParseObject from the JsonObject which is coming through the notifications?

Comment: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/84

Comment: Thankyou but the answer is to use ParseObject.fromJSON() method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Best way to do it is to use the  ParseObject.fromJSON() method.

It takes three parameters : JsonObject , DefaultClassName , ParseDecoder

An example code would be :

`ParseDecoder decoder = ParseDecoder.get();
ParseObject obj = ParseObject.fromJSON(MyJsonObject,"object_class_name", decoder);`